# how to present json files and directories?

Tags: json, directory, filesystems

I have the following json file , how could I represent the the list of files and the documents, and when i press on a document it will show the files inside ?

```
{  
   "d_type":"directory",
   "name":".",
   "size":1020,
   "subdirectory":[  
      {  
         "d_type":"file",
         "name":".DS_Store",
         "size":15364
      },
      {  
         "d_type":"directory",
         "name":"simplejson-3.6.5",
         "size":578,
         "subdirectory":[  
            {  
               "d_type":"file",
               "name":".DS_Store",
               "size":12292
            },
            {  
               "d_type":"directory",
               "name":"build",
               "size":170,
               "subdirectory":[  
                  {  
                     "d_type":"directory",
                     "name":"bdist.macosx-10.9-intel",
                     "size":68,
                     "subdirectory":[  

                     ]
                  },
                  {  
                     "d_type":"directory",
                     "name":"lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7",
                     "size":102,
                     "subdirectory":[  
                        {  
                           "d_type":"directory",
                           "name":"simplejson",
                           "size":374,
                           "subdirectory":[  
                              {  
                                 "d_type":"file",
                                 "name":"init.py",
                                 "size":23137
                              },
                              {  
                                 "d_type":"directory",
                                 "name":"tests",
                                 "size":986,
                                 "subdirectory":[  
                                    {  
                                       "d_type":"file",
                                       "name":"test_unicode.py",
                                       "size":6996
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {  
                     "d_type":"directory",
                     "name":"temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7",
                     "size":102,
                     "subdirectory":[  
                        {  
                           "d_type":"directory",
                           "name":"simplejson",
                           "size":102,
                           "subdirectory":[  
                              {  
                                 "d_type":"file",
                                 "name":"_speedups.o",
                                 "size":268464
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Please, provide some context. Right now it is really hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".